# Ayuda en codigo en c++

Tags: c++

queria preguntarles como poder terminar esta parte de codigo, en el cual en la parte
del else if se pregunta si el nodo es menor que el anterior o mayor que el siguiente o agregar en el
medio.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

// definicion de estructuras
typedef struct tnodo* pnodo;
struct tnodo
{
  int dato;
  pnodo ant;
  pnodo sig;
};

struct tlista
{
  pnodo inicio;
  pnodo fin;
};

// prototipos de funciones y procedimientos
void agregarenroden(tlista& lis, pnodo nuevo);

// la idea del ejercicio de agregar en orden es que el nodo se agregue en la
// posición correcta, si la lista está vacía se agrega directamente, si tiene
// elementos se consideran los casos que sea menor que el primero, mayor que el
// último o bien si se agrega en medio
void agregarenorden(tlista& lis, pnodo nuevo)
{
  if (lis.inicio == NULL)
  {
    lis.inicio = nuevo;
    lis.fin = nuevo;
  }
  else if (nuevo < lis.inicio &&
           nuevo > lis.fin)    // aqui  hacer la modificacion para poder agregar
                               // los elementos en orden
  {
    nuevo->ant = lis.fin;
    lis.fin->sig = nuevo;
    lis.fin = nuevo;
  }
  lis.inicio->ant = lis.fin;
  lis.fin->sig = lis.inicio;
}
```

la correccion seria en el else if. O si deberia hacer un insertar inicio, final.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 0):

No deberías pasar un nodo, sino un valor. Y en agregarEnOrder lo que se haría es que si ese valor no se encuentra en la lista, recién crea un nuevo nodo con ese valor; si ya existe, no hay nada que hacer.

Luego, al comparar `nuevo < lis.inicio`, estás comparando las memorias a las que apuntan los punteros, no los valores. Para acceder a los valores tienes que usar el operador `->`. De la siguiente forma: `nuevo->dato < lis.inicio->dato`.

La forma mas simple de ver las operaciones en una lista enlazada es considerando tres casos:

- Cuando el valor se va a insertar como la nueva cabeza (inicio)
- Cuando el valor se va a insertar entre dos nodos
- Cuando el valor se va a insertar al final de toda la lista

PD: Antes de publicar tu código, procura que lo que has publicado sea un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Buenas noches, tengo la lista doble, andar insertar inicio e insertar final, tengo las funciones de insetrar antes de y despue de, si es posible puedes ayudarme en el siguiente codigo que compila, pero necesitaria adapar insertar antes_de e insertar_despues_de: